# MariaDB Select count of values by keys

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table and I want to get count of common values by 2 keys...
For example, if I put keys 1981 and 1975 I get count of 3 (both of them have 2255, 2228, 2232) etc. I only know how to solve it by PHP but It's much slower than doing by SQL. Thanks

[image: Table Sample]

Full Table Dump (mysql commands): [DUMP](https://zerobin.net/?e0c02de9e9ea7e81#6ot3jFy1w5abIc41SoT3SyCz+Zd7KJB22UCG5oE+leA=)

PHP-ish solution would be (from scratch, without optimalization):
(And sorry for pseudo-code-ish text)

```
$1 = Select * From tbl Where Key = key1;
$2 = Select * From tbl Where Key = key2;

$counter = 0;
foreach($1 as $item)
{
    foreach($2 as $item2)
    {
        if($item->value == $item2->value)
        {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}

return $counter;
```

Comment: [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and why did you not upload the PHP code ? Then we might have a better clue at what you are trying to do.

Comment: please reade https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: [Using hyperlinks to external sites on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387708/using-hyperlinks-to-external-sites-on-so)   There are some exceptions like dbfiddle, but you are expected to post the SQL code on SO too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation.

First, with this query:

```
SELECT value
FROM stats
WHERE `key` IN (1981, 1975)
GROUP BY value
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 // the number of values that you search for
```

you get the `value`s that satisfy the condition that both `key`s belong to them and then use it as a subquery to count the `value`s:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT value
  FROM stats
  WHERE `key` IN (1981, 1975)
  GROUP BY value
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vuH3SYKc222ewuDk6e8aHS/0).

Comment: Oh... Having Count... that is the mising link i could not find. working solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
CREATE TABLE `keyvalue` (
  `v` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `k` int DEFAULT NULL
);

insert into keyvalue values 
   (1,1982),(2,1982),(3,1982),
   (1,1975),(2,1975),(3,1975),(4,1975),
   (3,1983);

select k1, k2
from (
   select 
      k1.k as k1,
      k1.v as v1, 
      k2.k as k2, 
      k2.v as v2, 
      row_number() over(partition by k1.k,k2.k) as R 
   from keyvalue k1 
   inner join keyvalue k2 on k1.k!=k2.k and k1.v=k2.v 
   ) x
where k2>k1
group by k1,k2
having max(R)=3
;
```

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4bbe5f32fba741f552bc137cfd5d1f7e)

Comment: This did not solve the problem, I need to give to SQL 2 inputs (k column) from your SQL for example 1 and 3 and output should be COUNT of common values (v column) -> in this case output should be 2. If I take k1 = 2 and k2 = 4 Output should be 1 (key 2 and 4 has common value only 1975). Hope this explanation is good enough.

Comment: ok, I must have missed the "expected output" in your question (they are talking about that in [mre])